# SQL Server: explode out view with CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a dataset as shown below:

```
ProductionOrder RootID  SalesOrder  Line    Quantity
829602  60124786_7275   60124786    7375    1
829603  60124786_7275   60124786    7400    1
109051  60126867_10000  60126867    10000   3
109058  60126867_10000  60126867    10050   3
109063  60126867_10000  60126867    10075   3
109071  60126867_10000  60126867    10125   3
109076  60126867_10000  60126867    10150   3
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to "explode" out this view into it's individual components for each quantity. For example, that last row (ProductionOrder: 109076) would look like this instead:

```
ProductionOrder RootID  SalesOrder  Line    QtyID
109076  60126867_10000  60126867    10150   1 of 3
109076  60126867_10000  60126867    10150   2 of 3
109076  60126867_10000  60126867    10150   3 of 3
```

And this would be done for every line, dynamic based on that total qty. I can achieve this with a loop, but this is thousands and thousands of rows, so I was wondering if anyone could help me with a CTE-based example of this. I am trying to wrap my head around it but it has proven to be difficult. Any ideas?

Comment: I've actually been using a stored procedure to move each row into a different view when it becomes relevant. I use CTE insert for that specific row. But, I am not super familar with windowed aggregation. I'll look more into that now. Thanks!

Comment: Aside: You might be better served by having two columns, e.g. `ItemCount` (`1`, `2`, ...) and `TotalItems` (`3`, `3`, ...), rather than `QtyId`. They are easily combined for display, but they avoid problems like sorting rows, e.g. "2 of 12" comes _after_ "10 of 12".

Answer (score 0):

This is not a runnable query, however, it should be enough to give you an idea on how to use recursion to replicate rows for a set number of times.

```
;WITH Normalized AS
(
    SELECT *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) FROM YourData
)
,ReplicateAmount AS
 (
    SELECT  ProductionOrder , RootID, SalesOrder, Line,  Quantity
    FROM Normalized

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.ProductionOrder , R.RootID, R.SalesOrder, R.Line, Quantity=(R.Quantity - 1)
    FROM ReplicateAmount R INNER JOIN Normalized N ON R.RowNumber = N.RowNumber
    WHERE R.Quantity > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ross. What is "Normalized" in this case?

Comment: That was a typo. I fixed it as a second query against your data.

Comment: You need to be able to derive a sequential value so that your recursive queries can be joined and matched to the corresponding record. In the example above it is done in the Normalize cte using the PK order of the table. If you have a field that can be used to order the records then replace the select 0 with that field.

Comment: You can now use the Normalized subquery as the source of both subqueries, changed it above.

Comment: With this new subquery, how is it referencing my data? There's no inherent call to "YourData"

Comment: Doh! Updated it in the Normalized subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily achieved with a Tally. If you have very small values, then a `JOIN` to a small `VALUES` clause works:

```
--Sample data
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(829602,'60124786_7275',60124786,7375,1),
                (829603,'60124786_7275',60124786,7400,1),
                (109051,'60126867_10000',60126867,10000,3),
                (109058,'60126867_10000',60126867,10050,3),
                (109063,'60126867_10000',60126867,10075,3),
                (109071,'60126867_10000',60126867,10125,3),
                (109076,'60126867_10000',60126867,10150,3))V(ProductionOrder,RootID,SalesOrder,Line,Quantity))
--Solution
SELECT ProductionOrder,
       RootID,
       SalesOrder,
       Line,
       CONCAT(V.I,' of ',YT.Quantity) AS QtyID
FROM YourTable YT
     JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I) ON V.I <= YT.Quantity
```

If, however, you have much larger values for `Quantity`, then a larger tally will be needed:

```sql
--Sample data
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(829602,'60124786_7275',60124786,7375,1),
                (829603,'60124786_7275',60124786,7400,1),
                (109051,'60126867_10000',60126867,10000,3),
                (109058,'60126867_10000',60126867,10050,3),
                (109063,'60126867_10000',60126867,10075,3),
                (109071,'60126867_10000',60126867,10125,3),
                (109076,'60126867_10000',60126867,10150,101))V(ProductionOrder,RootID,SalesOrder,Line,Quantity)),
--Solution
N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM(VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1,000 rows, add more N's for more rows
SELECT ProductionOrder,
       RootID,
       SalesOrder,
       Line,
       CONCAT(T.I,' of ',YT.Quantity) AS QtyID
FROM YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON T.I <= YT.Quantity
ORDER BY ProductionOrder,
         T.I;
```

Comment: What would be considered a large number for quantity? For my data, values could go up to maybe 10, 15 at the highest.

Comment: Well for the *larger* number of rows I exampled a value of `100` for `quantity` and handled up to 1,000 rows, @skyfarhan.

Comment: Could you explain the `JOIN` statement? Why is it values up to VALUES(10)?

Comment: `JOIN` is quite a basic part of SQL, @sykfarhan, I suggest reading the documentation and tutorials if you don't understand them. As for why up to `10`, because I didnt' know how many you needed, and humans to tend to operate in groups of 10.

Comment: Sorry, I understand the `JOIN`, just didn't know if there was a specified reason that it was up to 10. Thanks for the help! This query runs well. Will have to test it for scalability later.

Comment: *"if there was a specified reason that it was up to 10"* none other than that people tends to work in decimals, @sykfarhan . As for scalability, that's what the tally version is for, as it scales far better than an rCTE, which is considerably [less performant](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/#multi).